# Intellisense doesn't work for one particular project in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Thanks in advance.
This problem has killed one whole day of my time.
Intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 works on all projects in my solution except one. It used to work until yesterday and today it just doesn't work particularly for that single project. Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Things I tried: deleted the .ncb file, restarted VS 2010, restarted PC, checked in tools->options-texteditor->c# and General settings to enable suggestions. But none of these steps helped me.

regards
Yash

Comment: maybe remove the project from the solution and re-add it?

Comment: Did you already tried to clean the solution `Build -> Clean solution` and then do a rebuild?

Comment: yes i did clean it. but that dint help. thanks for response i found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced a similar problem after editing some code when running the debugger. What I did was exit debugging mode, restart VS 2010 and Rebuild Solution. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Does the same thing happen on a different pc in the same solution?

If it does, try adding the same files to a new project and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try to [run VS 2010 in safe mode.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

If Safe Mode does not help at all, go to **Tools** > **Options...**, click **Text Editor** to collapse, then click **All languages**. Under **Statement completion**, make sure you check (tick) them all.

**Update:** You can also try [resetting your VS 2010 settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help anyone but I got the problem to resolve by deleting the ncb file AND the suo file. After that (In VS 2008) the Statement completion option as described by eibhrum had one grayed out box (checked) and the Display option had all boxes grayed out (and checked). I checked them all.

I tried checking just the statement options (prior to my deletion of both the ncb and suo files) and that did not work. I never tried checking the display options before during my last two hours of multiple attempts to resolve this issue (I like 'Yash' had one project that did not work; yet resetting that project back to the cpp and h file it had yesterday when it worked did not resolve the problem).

I think (note think) that deleting the suo file is a hard reset your settings option.

In the end I don't understand why the problem arises so its a damn frustrating trial and error. Maybe my approach will help someone out there. Its certainly a very common problem!